# Kafka resource leaks

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

`Note: after creating a KafkaProducer you must always close() it to avoid resource leaks.`

went through the documentation but could not understand it. Can anyone explain what it really means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have to use [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on it, or `close` it explicitly when you are done using this producer. `Producer` implements `Closable` and does many cleanup routines when `#close()` method is being called, such as stopping threads and closing i/o streams. Same goes for `Consumer`.

Resource leaks in general may cause performance issues, such prevent proper work of GC, exhaust available limits of file handlers, cause network slowdown and so on.